# Copy Raster for a Raster Mosiac with Function produces corrupted data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem

I am trying to export a ArcGIS raster mosaic dataset to a new raster that has a "Elevation Void Fill" function on it to fill holes in the data, but I am finding the function data is getting corrupted when exporting to a new raster.

Any ideas on how to remedy this?

**Orignal .tif file**

[image: Original]

**Mosaic dataset raster with function to fill gaps**

[image: Mosaic with function]

**Exported to new raster by Copy Raster Tool**

[image: Exported to new raster by Copy Raster Tool]

Comment: Could you please supply more details on your workflow?

Comment: I made small edits, but it should be pretty clear to the workflow if you've used raster functions.

Comment: Great, thanks for the edit. Also, which method are you using to export the corrected mosaic?

Comment: Copy Raster Tool

Comment: (Copy Raster Tool) result seems without a background so I guess that you ignored the background value. Also in Copy raster Tool? did you specify the same (Pixel Type) as your original raster?. Did you change some parameters of the Copy Raster Tool.

Comment: I tried with a mask, without a mask, I made sure I was using the same pixel type (32bit float), tried .tif and esri grid.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156156)